# How to run two different versions of Nodejs simultaneously on a Windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Having issues in running two different versions of Nodejs on a Windows machine simultaneously

Comment: do you mean something like NVM. but not sure if can be run simultaneous

Comment: @Santosh, can you explain how did you try it (You can update your post with the details)? Also, better to explain what was the issue you faced.

Comment: @cmgchess I don't see why not. Surely, it's just a matter of launching two Node processes from two different executables. I don't know the best way to do it but I can't see why it wouldn't be possible to do that on one machine.

Comment: Why not use docker to run two or even more node containers ?

Comment: Install them on different folders and run each one of them separately.

Comment: I surely is possible, although it might be a bit of a hassle to get two totally distinct installations of node on your system, because a typical node installation places some content in your user's profile folder (for instance the global .npmrc file or globally installed packages) why would you need two different versions of node at the same time?

Comment: Also can you elaborate more on what are you trying to do and why you need tow version running on same machine at same time?

Comment: @derpirscher I can see the need for two installations - different projects might have a different Node dependency and if you want to run two at a time, you might not be able to with just one Node installation. It's honestly a pretty bad setup from Node. They introduced [the "engines" flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) relatively recently for it. There is that whole NVM which *attempts* to alleviate that but only if you're running each application one at a time. I'm not aware how to easily use NVM to launch an application with a specific version of Node.

Comment: @Sohan I'm a bit amazed and slightly afraid that people seem to be dismayed about launching two Node applications. Does that...not happen? You develop one application then two years later you make another and want to run them both on the same machine. But Node version and dependencies have shifted drastically in the mean time. I come from a Java background and the concept of two applications needing different runtimes is routinely applicable. One application requires Java 6 another Java 9. Java is even more backwards compatible than Node but still the best practice is to have separate JREs.